# Excel vba mistakes one range for the other

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sub that opens workbook, puts its particular range into a variable and them passes that variable as an argument to a function that is supposed to MsgBox each value of the range and change it.

```
Function testFunc(aCol As Range)
  Dim i As Integer
  i = 0
  For Each cell In aCol
    MsgBox (cell.Value)
    cell.Value = i
    i = i + 1
  Next

  testFunc = i
End Function


Sub testSub()   
    Dim dataWorkbook As Workbook
    Set dataWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open("Y:\vba\test_reserves\test_data\0503317-3_FO_001-2582480.XLS")

   Set imcomesNamesRange = dataWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet 1").Range("A1:A20")
   Cells(1, 5) = testFunc(aRange)
End Sub
```

But it doesn't happen - it only MsgBoxes values of the curren workbook's worksheet's range (that workbook which contains the macros) instead of reading and editing the newly opened workbook. What is wrong here?

Comment: `testFunc(aRange)`? or `testFunc(imcomesNamesRange)`? I urge you to use `Option Explicit`, it will save you a lot of debugging time. Also please post the code you are testing **as is** using copy/paste.

Comment: @ A.S.H , ops, didn't notice thanks. Might be deleted then

Comment: Function should only be used if you are expecting a value to be returned, you should change Function testFunc to Sub testFunc

Comment: @ jmdon i'm returning a value to Cells(1,5)

Comment: What workbook is the `Cells(1,5)` to be on? I'm assuming it should be the *original* workbook, not `dataWorkbook`, correct? If so, make sure to add say `Dim origWB as Workbook` // `Set origWB = ActiveWorkook` *before* you open the other and then do `origWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,5) = ...`.  Without qualifying the worbook and sheet with `Range()`/`Cells()`, VBA uses whatever the activesheet is.